# How to merge values from two different text files?

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have following data set in text files:

**file1.txt**

```
a1:b1
a2:b2
a3:b3
a4:b4
a5:b5
```

**file2.txt**

```
b2:c1
b4:c2
b5:c3
```

How to merge these values to make output file like this:

**output.txt**

```
a2:c1
a4:c2
a5:c3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your files appear to contain sorted data, you should be able to use the `join` command e.g.

```
join -12 -21 -t: -o1.1,2.2 file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

Then

```
cat output.txt
a2:c1
a4:c2
a5:c3
```

See `man join` for details of the options.

If the files are **not** pre-sorted, then you can sort them first using process substitution. *Note however that the sort must be on the field on which you want to join the files* e.g.

```
join -12 -21 -t: -o1.1,2.2 <(sort -t: -k2,2 file1.txt) <(sort -k1,1 file2.txt)
androgynous:hu2nt
gra7vel:fi6nal
cosm4etic:citizen
```

The result will also be in sorted order: if you don't want that, then there is a fairly standard way to do this kind of thing in `awk` using an array e.g.

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next;} ($1 in a) {print a[$1]":"$2;}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: `join` seems to be a great tool for that :)

Comment: use > output.txt to redirect steeldriver's solution to text file

Comment: @Meow thanks for the catch - edited accordingly

Comment: @summertime-sadness If the files are not sorted, sort them and pass them to `join` using a process substitution: `join -12 -21 -t: -o1.1,2.2 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > output.txt`

Comment: @terdon oops :( what are the chances? anyhow I have upvoted your answer for the nice clear explanations

Answer (score 5):

Here's an `awk` approach:

```
awk -F: '(NR==FNR){a[$2]=$1; next}($1 in a){print a[$1]":"$2};' file1 file2 > out
```

#### Explanation

- `awk -F:` Run `awk`, setting the field separator to `:`. This will read each input line and split it on `:`. So, for the first line of `file1`, the 1st field (`$1`) is `a1` and the second (`$2`) is `b1`.
- `(NR==FNR){}` : If `NR` is equal to `FNR`. `NR` is the current input line number and `FNR` is the line number of the current file. The two will be equal only while the 1st file is being read.
- `a[$2]=$1; next` : save the second field as a key in array `a` whose value is the 1st field. Then, skip to the next line.
- `($1 in a){print a[$1]":"$2}` : this will execute only while reading the second file. If the first field of the second file is a key array `a`, print the value for that key (the 2nd field of the corresponding line from `file1`).

---

And a Perl one:

```
perl -F: -lanE '$k{$F[0]} ? say "$k{$F[0]}:$F[1]" : ($k{$F[1]}=$F[0]);' file1 file2 > out
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
perl -F: -lanE '$k{$F[0]} and say "$k{$F[0]}:$F[1]" or ($k{$F[1]}=$F[0]);' file1 file2
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -F: -lanE` : The `-n` means "read each input file line by line and apply the script given by `-E` to each of them" . `-E`, like `-e`, lets you pass a script on the command line. The difference is that `-E` enables some extra features such as `say`. The `-a` enables automatic splitting of each input line on the character given by `-F`. Together, they make `perl` act much like `awk`. Fields are split into array `@F` and the 1st field is `$F[0]`, the 2nd `$F[1]` etc. Finally, `-l` strips newline (`\n`) characters from the end of each line.
- `$k{$F[0]} ? foo : bar`: If the variable `$k{$F[0]}` is defined, do foo, else do bar.
- `($k{$F[1]}=$F[0])` : this happens if `$k{$F[0]}` is not defined (it is the "bar", above). It will save the second field as a key in the hash `%k` whose value is the 1st field.
- `say "$k{$F[0]}:$F[1]"` : this will run if `$k{$F[0]}` is defined (the "foo" above), so if the 1st field of the current line was a 2nd field in another line. If it was, print (`say` is like `print` but adds a newline) the 1st field of the current and the value associated with it in the hash.

Comment: Great :) if I may say so.

Comment: Nice! For `awk` it may be even cleaner to set OFS instead of hardcoding it when printing. I like doing it with `BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"}` for cases like this, when FS and OFS are the same.